# Use of enumerate and mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, enumerate

```
newResidues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
newI = [[1,0,1,0,1],[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0]]
newI = np.array(newI)

for i in range(newI.shape[0]):
    indices = [for i,num in enumerate(newI) if num == 1] #line1
    indicesToResidues = dict(zip(indices,newResidues[indices]))#line2
```

So I know my code is incorrect... this is just an attempt of what I'm trying to do...

in line1 what I'm trying do is make a list of the indices wherever there is a 1 in the matrix for each row, separately. So indices for the first row of the matrix would look something like [0,2,5]

in line 2 trying to map these indices to a particular value with the same index in a list newResidues.

Any help/comments will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `newI.shape[0]` that doesn't match with the pure-python definition above.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre thanks for pointing that out, fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your loop with the following:

```
from itertools import compress
for i in newI:
    print map(lambda _: newResidues.index(_), compress(newResidues, i))
```

[`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) is pretty neat and seems perfect for your use case. After the above gets the values back from `compress` it finds the index of each value from `newResidues` -- this won't work correctly if you have duplicate values in `newResidues` however!

Comment: So, when I print it, it gives me the correct indices values. Although, can you help me understand how I can access the values from my list newResidues with these indices? (this is actually a new question - would you like me to post it separately?)

Comment: If you want to return just the values you can just use `compress(newResidues, i)` and you'll get the original values back.